# União de Vetores em C

Tags: c, array

boa noite. Estou com uma atividade avaliativa da faculdade para ser entregue mas não consigo pensar na lógica e resolver a primeira atividade. Alguém pode me explicar onde está o meu erro e um conselho para entender melhor índices em for. Faço uma confusão arretada com eles.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>


/*DECLARAÇÃO DE VARIAVEIS*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int veta[10], vetb[10], vetu[20], vetd[10];
    int i, x, y, z, w, k;

    /*VETORES RECEBEM DADOS*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    printf("\n\t\t\tInsira os valores de VETOR A\n\n");


    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Inserção dos valores ao vetor A
    {
        printf("Insira o valor do vetor A [%i]: ", i+1);
        scanf("%i", &veta[i]);

        vetu[i] = veta[i];      //ATRIBUI VALOR DO VETOR A AO VETOR C DIRETAMENTE.
    }

    printf("\n\t\t\tInsira os valores de VETOR B\n\n");


    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Inserção dos valores ao vetor A
    {
        printf("Insira o valor do vetor A [%i]: ", i+1);
        scanf("%i", &vetb[i]);

        vetu[i+10] = vetb[i];   //ATRIBUI VALOR DO VETOR B AO VETOR C A PARTIR DA POSIÇÃO 10
    }


    /*VETOR B - RECEBE DADOS*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    printf("\n\t\t\tA União dos vetores A e B\n\n");

    for(x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        for(y = 0; y < 20; y++)
        {
            if(vetu[y] == veta[x])
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                vetu[y] = veta[x];
            }

        }
    }

    for(x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", vetu[y]);
    }

}
```

O código deveria me mostrar (Todos os valores que contem no VETOR A e no VETOR B sem repetição. Ou seja, se o usuário digitar [1][2][3][3][4][5] E [6][5][3][7][8], o programa deveria me dar a seguinte saída: [1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8].

Mas não é isso que acontece...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o seu código de achar a união não está correto, tanto em termos de lógica como implementação. Na verdade esta a fazer um laço/ciclo de `0` a `19` com `x`:

```
for(x = 0; x < 20; x++)
```

E depois testa o vetor A:

```
if(vetu[y] == veta[x])
```

Quando na verdade esse tem apenas `10` elementos, o que só por si está incorreto e pode-lhe dar um *Segmentation fault*. Para além disso não está a utilizar o `vetb`, assim como também não está a remover as repetições e sim apenas a reescrever valores.

Proponho que faça antes assim:

```
int tamanho2 = 20; //começa com o tamanho que definiu para a união

for(x = 0; x < 20; x++)
{
    //começa no numero seguinte ao x e vai apenas até ao tamanho2
    for(y = x + 1; y < tamanho2; y++) 
    {
        //se é um elemento repetido no vetu. Note que já não uso ==veta[x] neste if.
        if(vetu[y] == vetu[x]) 
        {
            //quando encontra vai até ao fim a puxar os elementos uma casa para trás
            //esta lógica acaba por remover o elemento repetido
            for (k = y; k < tamanho2-1; k++){
                vetu[k] = vetu[k+1];
            }

            //depois de ajustar os elementos "diminuir" o tamanho do array resultante
            tamanho2--; 
        }
    }
}
```

[Exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/ogl4Mv)

Repare que utilizei apenas o `vetu` que era o vetor que tinha todos os elementos, e removi as repetições dele próprio ajustando o tamanho e puxando elementos.

No final ficou em `tamanho2` a quantidade de elementos sem repetições do array, que será o que deve utilizar a seguir para a escrita na consola.

**Nota**: Na ultima parte da escrita também tem um pequeno erro que convêm corrigir:

```
for(x = 0; x < 20; x++)
{
    printf("%i\n", vetu[y]);
    //------------------^ tem de ser x e não y
}
```

#### Outras alternativas

Poderia ter seguido outras soluções que garantem melhor complexidade de tempo, mas já são bastante mais elaboradas e provavelmente não vão de encontro às soluções que esperam para o exercício. Tentei usar a mais parecida com a  que estava a utilizar.

Exemplo de soluções alternativas com melhores complexidades:

- Usar uma tabela de dispersão (hash table) e fazer uma inserção dos elementos nesta tabela o que irá evitar repetições e dar uma solução na ordem de `O(n)`. Irá complicar se precisar de uma escrita na mesma ordem em que foram inseridos.
- Ordenar o array resultante com um método eficiente tipo *QuickSort* ou *MergeSort* que lhe garante `O(nlogn)` e depois remover as repetições que será `O(n²)`  ou `O(n)` se passar os não repetidos para um novo array.
- Se não precisa do array resultante (que não foi claro na pergunta) pode seguir outra implementação excluindo o `vetu`. Esta iria percorrer `A` e mostrar os que não existem em `B` e vice-versa, que lhe dá `O(n²)`